# How do force center-alignment in a caption in a figure?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, apa6

When I use the following code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \caption{test}
    \includegraphics{intpoptotal.png}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

The caption is centered as I want it, e.g.,

[image]

But when I use [this apa6 class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6), with the following code:

```
    \documentclass{apa6}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \caption{test}
    \includegraphics{intpoptotal.png}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

The caption is left-aligned, e.g.,

[image]

How can I use `\documentclass{apa6}` with centered captions?  And what code in apa6 causes this to happen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`apa6.cls` loads the `caption` package with the option `singlelinecheck=off`:

```
\RequirePackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
```

this option overrides the standard LaTeX behaviour  (automatically center a
caption if it fits in one single line). To change this, you can use `\captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass{apa6}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=on}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{test}
A
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Notice that this will center only captions that fit on one line; if you want to have all captions centered (whether they span one or more than one line), you can say

```
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
```

As a side note, it's preferable to use `\centering` inside the floating environments instead of the `center` environment (`\centering` doesn't add additional vertical space); also, I would suggest you not to use the too restrictive placement specifier `[!h]`.