# How to centre a specific caption?

Tags: captions, ieeeconf

I know that the same question was already discussed in the forum. 
The suggestion was to use `\usepackage{caption}` ..

I use `\documentclass{ieeeconf}` instead of `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{caption}` changes the format of all table captions automatically.

Now my question is: How can I change the caption of a specific figure without changing any other caption?

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this problem.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried `\begingroup \captionsetup{<options>} \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} \endgroup`?

Comment: The default of `ieeeconf` is to have the captions centred. Did you know that?

Comment: a little example would help give a better answer, but did you try something like this ?
  `\centering` then `\caption{whatever}`

take a look at this
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60344/how-do-force-center-alignment-in-a-caption-in-a-figure

Comment: @Mico: Isn't it simpler to write `\begin{figure}\captionsetup{…} … \end{figure}`?

Comment: @Bernard - You are quite likely right. I wish the OP would provide more specific information about his/her document setup, so that providing a specific solution might become feasible.