# Figure caption centering

Tags: floats, captions

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.80]{sysmodel.JPG}
\caption{System model} \label{m1}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
```

I am using the above code but the position of the figure caption is not in center. It needs to be center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do force center-alignment in a caption in a figure?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60344/how-do-force-center-alignment-in-a-caption-in-a-figure)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments out of context. Are you using `twocolumn` mode?

Comment: Are you using the `caption` package? There are some parameters which can make the caption to be not centred.

Comment: It is important to know which document class you are using, which packages you load, and with which options.  But don’t use the `center` environment inside a figure: use `\centering`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Does this rule of `center` within `figure` hold for `figure*` too? It's not really a floating environment, is it?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What do you mean, when you say that `figure*` is not a floating environment?  Of course it is…

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: I thought, the main purpose of `figure*` is to span over columns? (Actually, I hate floats, therefore I don't use them ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, but in order to do so… it *has* to float, hasn’t it?

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment within `figure*`. It will add unwanted vertical spaacing. Use `\centering` instead.